# Is there any structure to .emacs file

Tags: emacs

I am trying to get into emacs. I have installed it using apt-get install on ubuntu.

Now I want to change the background color, and found some doc on this. The best doc I found is this: 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameParameters

But when reading about how to add things to the .emacs file, none of the docs/info I found mention anything about structure, and the .emacs file just looks like a big mess. Do any of you experienced emacs users follow a specific structure when adding to .emacs, or do you just add anywhere?

I want to add the following:

```
 (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "white"))
 (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "black"))
 (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(cursor-color . "coral"))
```

When opening the .emacs file, I don't file like just throwing it in, as I like structure. Before I try to make my own, I'd like to hear if there is a convention that I have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.emacs` file is a piece of Lisp code.  There are conventions for how to format Lisp code, but I guess that's not really what you are looking for.

Part of the problem is that your `.emacs` will tend to grow organically, as you find new things you want to try and new knobs you want to tweak.  Over time, it will build up into a huge, monolithic piece of unrelated code snippets.

The usual structuring conventions for code apply -- group related code together, add comments, modularize.

What you can do with the code you posted as an example is mainly to add a comment.

```
;; Frame colors

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "white"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "black"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(cursor-color . "coral"))
```

Some people like to add [folding mode markers](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FoldingMode) so they can collapse/expand code sections, but perhaps at that point you should start thinking about breaking it up into smaller files.

Overhauling the rest of your `.emacs` file is out of scope here, and impossible without access to the full thing.  But see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DotEmacsModular for some suggestions.  (Disclosure: A snippet of mine is prominently linked.)

Using [`customize`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) also helps somewhat, but it has its own pros and cons.  The `customize` settings are added programmatically at the end of your `.emacs`, and has very little by way of structure.